# Как прочитать бинарный файл по смещению?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Суть задачи в том что нужно получить одно дробночисловое значение с большого бинарного файла (~600 MB). Но как это сделать не загружая весь файл в память, а только определенный фрагмент?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html см. аргумент `position` у методов чтения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import fs from 'node:fs';

const stream = fs.createReadStream(
  './yarn.lock',
  { start: 10 }
);
stream.once('readable', () => {
  /** @type { Buffer } */
  const x = stream.read(50);
  console.log(x);
  console.log(x.toString('utf-8'));
  stream.close();
});
```

```bash
$ node read-file-fragment.js 
<Buffer 65 20 69 73 20 67 65 6e 65 72 61 74 65 64 20 62 79 20 72 75 6e 6e 69 6e 67 20 22 79 61 72 6e 20 69 6e 73 74 61 6c 6c 22 20 69 6e 73 69 64 65 20 79 6f>
e is generated by running "yarn install" inside yo
```